# Have a compatible certificate with itext7?

Tags: itext7

I would like to use certificate with itext7.

Where can i have/buy a certificate ?
I have seen a multiple website..., 
But which will be compatible with itext7.

Comment: Are you talking about a License to use iText7 commercially? Or about a certificate for making digital signatures?

Comment: certificate for making digital signatures

Comment: In the context of digital signatures, there's no special thing that makes a certificate compatible with iText7. You can use any valid certificate with iText7.

Answer (score 0):

Any valid certificate is compatible to use with iText7.

You can create your own certificate using OpenSSL. Here is a quick guide to OpenSSL which I found to be very useful.

[OpenSSL Essentials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs)

Comment: @GoRoger OpenSSL will allow you to create a self-signed certificate, which if installed on the system will show up as valid. If you need something more than that you will need to buy a certificate from a authorized CA.